# How to stop maven-deploy-plugin:deploy-file deploying source?

Tags: maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a WAR project that also produces some extra artefacts that I want to deploy to my artifact repo. So I have configured executions under the deploy plugin to deploy each of the extra artefacts

```
<execution>
    <id>deploy-exe</id>
    <phase>deploy</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <file>target/${project.build.finalName}.exe</file>
        <packaging>exe</packaging>

        <!-- pom, sources and javadoc already deployed by project. Release repo will fail redeployment  -->
        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
        <sources/>
        <javadoc/>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

But each execution will try and deploy the javadoc and sources for the project, even though I have tried to explicitly switch them off for the execution. NB I want javadoc and sources for the project, but I only want them deployed once (by deploy mojo).

This isn't a big deal until it comes to release time at which point my build breaks because it tries to deploy the javadoc and source for the deploy mojo as well as each of the deploy-file mojo executions to a release repo that doesn't allow redeploy of artifacts.

Is it possible to configure the maven-deploy-plugin to not deploy source & javadoc for the deploy-file mojo?

Comment: I also have this issue.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Pretty sure I used the attach-artefact goal of the build-helper-maven-plugin. See http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html